# Bolt head type - 12 tip star?

Tags: tools, bolts

I am changing my van's front seat and I found the bolt in the image.

[image: Bolt with a 12-pointed Torx-like head]

I don't seem to find what kind of head it is, nor what tool should I use for it.

Since it has 12 "tips" I'm guessing a big enough torx should work, but I don't have one that is big enough (tried a T45 and was too small)

Any ideas or tips?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "12 tip" bolt head you are seeing is called a "triple square". These come in bits for the bolt heads like you have and also as a nut which would require a socket to take them off. They are easily confused for torx, but are actually quite different.

Here is the [60850 Lisle set](https://www.lislecorp.com/specialty-tools/triple-square-set). You can also find an assortment on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=triple+square+bit+set).

**EDIT:** If you don't have a way to get the bits, something else you can do is either use square stock of the right size, or you can take a piece of metal and grind it square, down to the right size to fit into four of the twelve points.  It's kind of a hack, but can work in a pinch.

Comment: Excellent answer. First time I read/hear about this type of bits. Thank you!